# Difference between two dates, expressed as Years, Months, Days

Tags: sql, date-difference

Trying to get the time elapsed between two dates.

Say the start date is 01/01/2015 and the end date is 04/05/2015 - how could I express the time elapsed as 4 months, 3 days?

Using SSMS 2012.

Comment: Specify dbms used. (Many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: Jan 1 to Apr 5, isn't that 3 months and 4 days?

Comment: @jarlh, let me guess: USA?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a bit tired today. But it would be easier if products and programmers could use ANSI/ISO date format only, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Hi all, using SSMS 2012 - and from UK, so date above is 4th May!

Answer (score 1):

Since Muhammad already gave an answer for MYSQL and SQL server I will just add that if you are using Oracle you can simply subtract the dates:

```
TO_DATE('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
TO_DATE('2015-04-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following tells you the difference between two dates in days, clearly you haven't told us your DBMS, so I posted two possibilities:

**MySQL Syntax:**

```
DATEDIFF(date1,date2) 
DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29')
```

**SQL Server Syntax:**

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
DATEDIFF(day,'2014-08-05','2014-06-05')
```

**Links:**

For MySQL, please visit: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

For SQL Server, please visit: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Comment: If you're running SQL Server, or? (Still no dbms specified in question.)

Comment: I have rectified the answer, hopefully it'll help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I need it expressed as years, months, days though, rather than just days.